# spring securty SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

```
@Component
public class TrackerAuthFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler{
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        if(exception.getClass().isAssignableFrom(DisabledException.class)){
            super.setDefaultFailureUrl("/accountRecovery");
        }       
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }
}
```

**SpringSecurity.java**

```
@Autowired
    private TrackerAuthFailureHandler trackerAuthFailureHandler;

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .failureHandler(trackerAuthFailureHandler);

    }
```

Is there anything wrong with my code. After authentication failure, Page is not redirect to "/accountRecovery" url.

Comment: Your redirection only comes in picture when account is disabled and not when authentication has failed.

Comment: That's what i am trying for. I disabled user account. still no redirection

Comment: How did you disabled the account?

Comment: Manually placing false in database